# Using named tuples in select statements

Tags: c#, generics, tuples, c#-7.0

Is there a nicer way to select a named tuple in C# 7 using a var target variable? I must be doing something wrong in example 1, or misunderstanding something completely. I seem to have to explicitly set the target type in order to do this.

```
//1. Fails to compile with "incorrect number of type parameters" issue.
var tuples = source.Select<(int A, int B)>(x => (x.A, x.B));

//2. Compiles
IEnumerable<(int A, int B)> tuples = toCheck.Select(x => (x.A, x.B));

//3. Compiles
var tuples = new HashSet<(int A, int B)>(source.Select(x => (x.A, x.B)));
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can just use `var`, but you need to make sure the tuple elements are actually named.

In C# 7.0, you need to do this explicitly:

```
var tuples = source.Select(x => (A: x.A, B: x.B));
foreach (var tuple in tuples)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.A} / {tuple.B}");
}
```

In C# 7.1, when the value in a tuple literal is obtained from a property or field, that identifier will implicitly be the element name, so you'll be able to write:

```
var tuples = source.Select(x => (x.A, x.B));
foreach (var tuple in tuples)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.A} / {tuple.B}");
}
```

See the [feature document](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/infer-tuple-names.md) for more details around compatibility etc.

Comment: Great, I didn't realise you could embed the names for the elements in the tuple inside the declaration like that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isnt it ``A= x.A`` as in anonymous types? ``var x = new { A = x.A, B = x.B };``

Comment: @RandRandom: That's just not the syntax for tuple element names. It's consistently `:` in both declaration and in tuple literals. Anonymous types are more like object initializers, "setting" properties (although the types are actually immutable)

Comment: ``That's just not the syntax for tuple element names.`` thats kinda my question, why didnt they use the same syntax? Seems odd, since it ``feels`` similar, for Devs like me who dont know the magic behind.

Comment: @RandRandom: Ignore my bit about declarations. but it *is* the same syntax used to provide argument names. Personally I'm okay with it - if anything, I think I'd prefer it if anonymous types had used colons.

Comment: Tuples are symmetrical with argument lists.

Answer (score 4):

`Select` takes 2 type parameters: `Select<TSource, TResult>`. A tuple `(int A, int B)` is only one type, you can write it also `ValueTuple<int, int>`. So you have to write both parameters if you want a named tuple

```
var tuples = source.Select<TypeOfSource, (int A, int B)>(x => (x.A, x.B));
```