# What is the correct C# syntax to send a List<> with more than one column to a method?

Tags: c#

What is the correct syntax for a method to receive this list as an argument?

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title })
    .ToListAsync();
MyMethod(customList);
```

This doesn't work...

```
private void MyMethod(List<int, int, string> inputList)
{
    // process the input list
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass an anonymous type to a method. You need to create an actual type instead.

Comment: Ref: [How to pass anonymous types as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters)

Comment: Lists don't have “columns”.

Comment: @stuartd Really?! I was certain it had to be possible. My attempt seemed so neat... Ok, so I'll just make a new POCO-class and use that, then?

Comment: @stuartd - How about dynamic as function parameter. Then one can pass Anon types.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava you can use dynamic, as one of the answers in the link shows. My preferred solution would be an actual class 100% of the time - as the method being called is private, it can be a private inner class. I have worked with code that uses dynamic in the past and I still use it  - but only when I absolutely have to. I like it when the compiler tells me something I have done is wrong, rather than an angry customer.

Comment: Or you could try named tuples https://stackoverflow.com/q/45631769/8024897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of creating an anonymous type, use this class instead:

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
    .Select(x => new MyClass { 
        Id = x.Id, 
        ParentId = x.ParentId, 
        Title = x.Title 
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

And your method would turn into:

```
private void MyMethod(List<MyClass> inputList) # or IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    // process the input list
    return;
}
```

As [@stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423941/what-is-the-correct-c-sharp-syntax-to-send-a-list-with-more-than-one-column-to/60424012#comment106892329_60424012) points out in the comments, you could also make `MyClass` a private class inside your main class since its only used for a private method:

```
public class Program {

    private class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    // Rest of code
}
```

This however depends on how the rest of your code is implemented.

Comment: As it's a private method, the clas could probably be a private nested class (i.e. defined within the class that uses it)

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of things are wrong here. I am guessing you are quite new to c#. I will try to explain as much as possible -

First,

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title })
.ToListAsync();
```

`customList` is not a collection of `<int, int, string>`. The syntax -

```
x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title }
```

means, `x` is an `anonymous object` that has 3 properties named `Id`, `ParentId`, `Title`.

Second,

The syntax used is a shortcut. The actual syntax will give you a much more clear picture -

```
x => new <anonymous object> { Id = x.Id, ParentId = x.ParentId, Title = x.Title }
```

Third,

Because of what I mentioned at (second), the type definition of the list is this -

```
List<object> customList = await db.MyDbTable
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title })
.ToListAsync();
```

Which is clearly not `List<int, int, string>` and will definitely not work. In fact list does not even support `List<int, int, string>`. List only takes one data type (`List<>`) not three (`List<,,>`). More details here  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

Fourth,

Since the list is of type `List<object>`, inside the function, the compiler does not know that the object contains `Id`, `ParentId` and `Title`. There are a lot of approach to fix that, you could use class or dynamic objects. The good approach is the class -

```
public class Data {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}

List<Data> customList = await db.MyDbTable
.Select(x => new Data { Id = x.Id, ParentId = x.ParentId, Title = x.Title })
.ToListAsync();

private void MyMethod(List<Data> inputList)
{
    // process the input list
    return;
}
```

or you could use value tuple. Read about them here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples -

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
.Select(x => (Id: x.Id, ParentId: x.ParentId, Title: x.Title ))
.ToListAsync();

private void MyMethod(List<(int Id, int ParentId, string Title)> inputList)
{
    //example 
    var item = inputlist.First())
    var id = item.Id;

    // process the input list
    return;
}
```

or you could use reflection since you already know that object has the properties. But this type of coding is not recommended and you should avoid. But still I am going to show how to use  -

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title })
.ToListAsync();

private void MyMethod(List<object> inputList)
{
    //example 
    var item = inputlist.First())
    var id = item.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(item) //but a lot slower and not recommended
    // process the input list
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since no one's mentioned it yet, you could also use a [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple):

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
    .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title))
    .ToListAsync();
MyMethod(customList);

...

private void MyMethod(List<Tuple<int, int, string>> inputList)
{
    // process the input list
    foreach (var item in inputList)
    {
        var id = inputList[0].Item1;
        var parentId = inputList[0].Item2;
        var title = inputList[0].Item3;
    }
    return;
}
```

Or a [`ValueTuple` in C# 7+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples):

```
var customList = await db.MyDbTable
    .Select(x => (x.Id, x.ParentId, x.Title))
    .ToListAsync();
MyMethod(customList);

...

private void MyMethod(List<(int, int, string)> inputList)
{
    // process the input list (same as above)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well This will work, BUT - this is susceptible to exceptions if you goof up with what goes  as dynamic parameter.

```
static void Main()
{
    var src = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        src.Add(i);
    }

    var linqRetval = src.Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x,
        First = $"Hello{x}",
        Second = $"World{x}"
    }).ToList();

    SomeFunction(linqRetval);
}

static void SomeFunction(dynamic input)
{
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
    }
}
```